# Trigger cronjob after 3 hours instead of every 3rd hour of the day

Tags: linux, cron, teamcity

In Teamcity, I would like to trigger a build 3 hours after another job is successful. I am using a **Schedule Trigger** with the check box checked for **Trigger only if watched build changes** and the cron set to **0 */3 * * ***. This would run at the 3rd hour of the day (like 6:00, 9:00, 12:00, 15:00,...). If my watched build is successful at 11:45 am then this build will trigger at noon and not wait for 3 hours. How can I make it wait for 3 hours?